# spree order.save stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I use spree 0.70 for implementation my eshop. In development state work everything fine. But when i deploy app to server order#populate doesnt work.
I found in log only stack level too deep, nothing more. Probably is it problem with relationships between models.

```
Started POST "/orders/populate" for 89.173.150.167 at 2011-11-11 23:23:20 +0100
Processing by OrdersController#populate as HTML
Parameters:  
{"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"B8zHc4a4NwW9TU9lqUrHvu/5O2i+6aKfiD0bEFJEUEM=", "products"=>{"1060500784"=>"1025786949"}, "quantity"=>"1", "button"=>""}  
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 148ms  

SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
```

Then I run console and try run

```
o=order.new
o.save!
```

[complete SQL log](http://pastie.org/2849879)

If i change cache_classes to false in production then work. My version of [gems](http://pastie.org/2849894). Gems are same in production and development state.

Comment: Note that you've dumped your hashed password to the pastie -- I hope it's nothing important. (Yeah, it'd be a pain to brute-force that, but still.) Incidentally, I noticed at the end a `ROLLBACK`. Why did it not commit at that point?

Comment: It's password of guest user. It do rollback because perform ruby error(stack level too deep - some recursive code executed), or I'm mistaken? [Here are queries of sucessfull order.save](http://pastie.org/2851388)

Comment: I thing that problem is [here](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/order.rb#L475)
order.after_create create new adjustment, which after_update call adjustment.order.update!, which call order.update_adjustments

`
    def update_adjustments
      self.adjustments.reload.each(&:update!)
    end
`

Comment: I solved problem writing order_decorator. I override [method](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/order.rb#L475) with [this](http://pastie.org/2851758). I hope that this workaround is not affected other relationships to order and adjustment model.

Comment: Don't forget to post your answer here and mark it as accepted, so someone else can more easily tell the solution in the future! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There was a supposed fix for this https://github.com/spree/spree/pull/766. See if that fixes your issue